# Which is better: that or which

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> This is the biggest mushroom **which** I have ever seen.

"Which" or "that"? Which one is grammatically correct in this sentence?

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/that-or-which

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, either can be used.

Stylistically, I follow Fowler's recommendation to use "which" to introduce parenthetical clauses and, **when grammatically possible**, "that" to introduce restrictive clauses. So I recommend "that" in your example because the clause is restrictive: you are specifying a subset of mushrooms, namely those mushrooms you yourself have seen.

But style is largely a matter of personal opinion.